# Difference between "to reel", "to swivel", "to whirl", and "to spin"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In a sentence describing two people dancing in a room:

> And they reeled, and swiveled, and whirled, and spun ...

What are the differences between those four actions?

Comment: What did the dictionary say?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In other contexts it might be important to distinguish the meanings, but this is an obvious instance of the rhetorical figure *synonymia* - the author is enhancing his effect by piling on different words to denote a circular dance. Given the alternating anapaests and iambs, I suspect this is verse – even if it isn't, the author is very skillfully employing rhythm for further enhancement.

Comment: When you add alternating anapaests and iambs to all that reeling, and swivelling, and whirling and spinning, I think it becomes an extreme sport.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Certainly *anapest, anapest, anapest, trochee. /
anapest, anapest, anapest, trochee. /
anapest, anapest, anapest, trochee. /
anapest anapest trochee.* kept the Lone Ranger in shape.

Comment: @tchrist Yes - he was often seen at masked balls.

Comment: @tchrist Well, since you guys have covered Rossini and Verdi, I guess to have ask if he was escorting the Girl of the Golden West?

Answer (score 1):

I forget who said, "All words are infinitely polysemous," but it's probably also true that 'No words are truly synonymous.' As StoneyB says above, the author is taking liberties with the semantics of the sentence to achieve an admirable rhythmic effect.

Coincidentally, I said to someone today, "I must be careful not to waltz off with the key." I then thought of possible substitutes for *waltz* in the pretty transparent idiom, and decided that I couldn't think of any that are actually used. (Apparently, the *shuffle* is a type of dance.) There are some amusing candidates - tango, foxtrot, conga, jive, passacaglia, slosh....

Comment: 'sashay' seems to be used interchangeably with 'waltz' and is originally dialect for chassée. -- how do I delete that failure?

Comment: Absolutely right. Language doesn't have any use for two words that are exactly the same; there's always contexts where you use one and not the other for some particular effect.

Comment: @JohnLawler Or, as in the original question, use many for some general effect.

Comment: _Rereduduplication_, it's called in the trade.

Comment: @JohnLawler Do I remember (well, clearly I've forgotten, but ...) that there's a special term for a word which is itself an instance of what it names? 'Rereduplication' would seem to fit.

Comment: No, that's different. Maybe what you want is _onomatopoeia,_ which only applies to sounds whose name sounds like they do; _cock-a-doodle doo, pop, blatt,_ etc.